# Uri getHost() returns null

Tags: android, uri

I create `Uri` like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
```

Where url is http://www.YouthAgSummit.com

When I'm trying to get host from it I receive null. What is the problem?

P.S. I'm trying to setup Intent-Filter for this `Uri` and `ACTION_VIEW`.

**UPDATE** Even for this one http://android.com/ from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html) I get null.

Comment: My url already have schema included. Also I need Uri to be correct cause I want to setup IntentFilter for it.

Comment: `When I'm trying to get host from it`. You are not showing the used code? Any specific reason?

Comment: I just call uri.getHost() right after parsing (which I posted above).

Comment: Why do you need the host separately to set up an intent? Where would you need it? You did not post the code where you set up the intent. Any specific reason?

Comment: My question is not about setting up an Intent. I'm asking the reason why uri.getHost() returns null and I posted all necessary code. Please, forget about Intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using [java.net.URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html) class instead of [android.net.Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html). They have same functionality for my needs (getting separate url parts like host, scheme etc.).